# How do I take a screenshot with selenium and synchronous JS

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, selenium, synchronous

I am writing an automated test in javaScript using a node library called webdriver-synch, which pretty much allows you to write selenium test without callbacks and promises. Utilizes the java Webdriver API. There is no documentation on how to do this.

I am having a difficult time understanding how to take and save a screenshot locally using this library. can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method which returns screenshot as a base64 encoded PNG.

```
driver.getScreenshot()
```

Source: https://github.com/groupon/webdriver-http-sync

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. But this is using webdriver-http-sync. Any adea about webdriver-synch? Having trouble getting webdriver-http-synch to connect to the server